# (Resolved, Bypassed) Grails: how to pass model to the view of another controller?

Tags: grails, view, model, controller

I'm new to grails and wasn't able to find answer how I can pass model between controllers.

I have such situation, that there are Potential Client view and Client Request views.

It is possible that user would like to create client request from potential client information.

I thought about filling model objects incide transorm action of *PotentialClientController* and **chain** it to the create action of *ClientRequestController*. It would be good if user will have ability to edit data before saving, and possibly he will decide not to save it. So I don't want to save filled *ClientRequest* instance inside **transform** action, I want to pass it to **create** view of another controller. And I don't want to process **params** inside **create** action. Of course I can pass id's of already existent objects and use them inside **create** action, but it would simplier for me to pass model.

What is the correct way to do it?

Below is sample of what I'm trying to do:
**Transform action of Potential Client Controller:**

```
def transform = {
    def requestor = User.getByUsername(principal.username)

    def potentialClientInstance = PotentialClient.get( params.id )
    boolean hasEnoughtRights = checkRights()
    if(!hasEnoughtRights) {
        redirect(controller: 'login', action: 'denied')
    }

    ClientRequest clientRequestInstance = new ClientRequest()

    ContactPerson contactPersonInstance = ContactPerson.get(potentialClientInstance?.contactPerson?.id)
    Contact mobilePhoneContactInstance
    Contact workPhoneContactInstance
    Contact homePhoneContactInstance
    Contact organizationPhoneContactInstance
    Contact emailContactInstance
    ...........................

    clientRequestInstance?.ownedBroker = requestor
    clientRequestInstance?.organization = Organization.get(potentialClientInstance?.organization?.id)
    clientRequestInstance?.brand = new Brand(name: clientRequestInstance?.organization?.getBrandsString())
    clientRequestInstance?.estateType = EstateTypeDic.get(potentialClientInstance?.estateType?.id)
    clientRequestInstance?.footageFrom = potentialClientInstance?.footageFrom
    clientRequestInstance?.footageTo = potentialClientInstance?.footageTo
    clientRequestInstance?.priceFrom = potentialClientInstance?.priceFrom
    clientRequestInstance?.priceTo = potentialClientInstance?.priceTo
    clientRequestInstance?.currency = CurrencyDic.get(potentialClientInstance?.currency?.id)
    clientRequestInstance?.requestComment = Comment.get(potentialClientInstance?.comment?.id)
    clientRequestInstance?.comments?.setComments(potentialClientInstance?.comments)
    clientRequestInstance?.district = District.get(potentialClientInstance?.address?.district)
    clientRequestInstance?.addedBy = requestor
    clientRequestInstance?.modifiedBy = requestor


    chain (controller: 'clientRequest', action: 'create', model: [clientRequestInstance:clientRequestInstance, contactPersonInstance:contactPersonInstance, mobilePhoneContactInstance:mobilePhoneContactInstance, workPhoneContactInstance:workPhoneContactInstance, homePhoneContactInstance:homePhoneContactInstance, organizationPhoneContactInstance:organizationPhoneContactInstance, emailContactInstance:emailContactInstance,])
}
```

**Create action of Client Request Controller**

```
def create = {
        def clientRequestInstance = new ClientRequest()
        clientRequestInstance.properties = params
        return ['clientRequestInstance':clientRequestInstance]
}
```

Comment: I guess I know the reason, this is due to creating new object inside create action :)
def clientRequestInstance = new ClientRequest()
But I still can't pass my model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple.

I used redirect in transform action and passed id of Potential Client as params:

```
def transform = {
        def requestor = User.getByUsername(principal.username)

        def potentialClientInstance = PotentialClient.get( params.id )
        boolean hasEnoughtRights = checkRights()
        if(!hasEnoughtRights) {
                redirect(controller: 'login', action: 'denied')
        }

    redirect(controller: 'clientRequest', action: 'create', params: [potentialClientId: params.id])
}
```

Then used this id got required Potential Client instance and filled model with the same code inside create action of Client Request Controller:

```
def create = {

        def clientRequestInstance = new ClientRequest()
        def requestor = User.getByUsername(principal.username)

        ContactPerson contactPersonInstance
        Contact mobilePhoneContactInstance
        Contact workPhoneContactInstance
        Contact homePhoneContactInstance
        Contact organizationPhoneContactInstance
        Contact emailContactInstance
        if(params.potentialClientId) {
            PotentialClient potentialClientInstance = PotentialClient.get(params.potentialClientId)

            clientRequestInstance = new ClientRequest()

            contactPersonInstance = ContactPerson.get(potentialClientInstance?.contactPerson?.id)

                          ...............................

            clientRequestInstance?.ownedBroker = requestor
            clientRequestInstance?.organization = Organization.get(potentialClientInstance?.organization?.id)
            clientRequestInstance?.organization?.ownedBroker = requestor
            String brands = clientRequestInstance?.organization?.getBrandsString()
            if(brands) {
                clientRequestInstance?.brand = new Brand(name: clientRequestInstance?.organization?.getBrandsString())
            }
            clientRequestInstance?.estateType = EstateTypeDic.get(potentialClientInstance?.estateType?.id)
            clientRequestInstance?.footageFrom = potentialClientInstance?.footageFrom
            clientRequestInstance?.footageTo = potentialClientInstance?.footageTo
            clientRequestInstance?.priceFrom = potentialClientInstance?.priceFrom
            clientRequestInstance?.priceTo = potentialClientInstance?.priceTo
            clientRequestInstance?.currency = CurrencyDic.get(potentialClientInstance?.currency?.id)
            clientRequestInstance?.requestComment = Comment.get(potentialClientInstance?.comment?.id)
            potentialClientInstance?.comments?.each {
                clientRequestInstance?.addToComments(it)
            }
            clientRequestInstance?.district = District.get(potentialClientInstance?.address?.district)
            clientRequestInstance?.addedBy = requestor
            clientRequestInstance?.modifiedBy = requestor

        } else {
            clientRequestInstance.properties = params
        }
        return ['clientRequestInstance': clientRequestInstance, 'contactPersonInstance': contactPersonInstance, 
            'mobilePhoneContactInstance': mobilePhoneContactInstance,
            'workPhoneContactInstance': workPhoneContactInstance,
            'homePhoneContactInstance': homePhoneContactInstance,
            'organizationPhoneContactInstance': organizationPhoneContactInstance,
            'emailContactInstance': emailContactInstance]
    }
```